# AccessDB - Navigation Pane Opens Unexpectedly

Tags: ms-access, vba

At the start of my app I make sure the Nav Pane is minimized (not hidden):

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.Minimize
```

However, when I attempt to create a LINK to a remote table, the Nav Pane opens unexpectedly.

> Inserted HansUp suggestion below

```
Dim strPath As String 
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strNewFile As String

strPath = Left(CurrentDb.NAME, InStrRev(CurrentDb.NAME, "\"))
strNewFile = strPath & "PostInv_Backend.accdb"

'>>>Inserted HansUp suggestion
Application.Echo False
'<<<

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", strNewFile, acTable, "Item", "Item"

'>>>Inserted HansUp suggestion
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.Minimize
Application.Echo True
'<<<
```

Yes, I can re-minimize, but this produces an annoying BLINK.  Is there anyway to avoid the NAV Pane from opening like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you eliminate the flicker if you turn `Echo` off just before you re-minimize?

Comment: @HansUp - Echo Off hides that annoying artifact.  Thanks once again!

Comment: I modified the code snippet above to insert my update...